# How to use C# to get Showplan via DDtek

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to use DDTek Ado.Net library for a Sybase Server in C# to find a query's show plan.

I was wondering if anyone knew how Sybase DDtek library can be used to do this. Here's some sample code of what I've tried before:

```
  using (SybaseConnection dbConnect = new SybaseConnection())
                {

                    dbConnect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SybaseDB"].ConnectionString;
                    dbConnect.StatisticsEnabled = true;

                    dbConnect.Open();



                    dbConnect.InfoMessage += OnInfoMessage;


                    SybaseCommand cmd = new SybaseCommand { CommandTimeout = 1000, Connection = dbConnect };


                    SybaseCommand cmd2 = new SybaseCommand { CommandTimeout = 1000, Connection = dbConnect };
                    cmd.CommandText = "SET SHOWPLAN ON";
                   // int ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd2.CommandText = mainSql;
                   SybaseDataReader sDR = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                   // var ansp = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    String plan = String.Empty;



                    //sql.ToString();
                    var stats1 = dbConnect.RetrieveStatistics();
                    //var ans = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    var stats2 = dbConnect.RetrieveStatistics();
                    //.ExecuteNonQuery();  // no value needed in return

                    //cmd.CommandText = "SET SHOWPLAN OFF";
                    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    dbConnect.Close();
                    dbConnect.Dispose();
                }
```

Where the    mainSql Variable is a call to a stored procedure around a select query and having the lines:

```
set showplan on 
--set noexec on
set fmtonly on
```

When run in RapidSQL, a show plan is generated with no data rows returned. Using debugger to drill into the returned object yielded no show plan info. Perhaps I was looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Don't use a stored procedure. Put the select query in mainSql variable. Don't execute with ExecuteReader, execute both Show Plan command and select query with .ExecuteNonQuery.

This triggers the InfoMessage Callback in the Errors object of the SybaseInfoArgs passed into it. These can be concatenated into a message similar to what you getin RapidSql.